# For Each loop enumerator expression and memory consumption

Tags: vb.net

According to the language specification [guide](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15039) for VB.NET Section 10.9.3

> The enumerator expression in a for each loop is copied over into
>   memory.

If I have a list of 10000 objects that list will be in memory twice for the code below?

```
dim myList as new list(of bobs)
'put 10000 bobs in my list
for each x In myList
'do something 
next
```

If I were generating the list from a linqQuery or some other such query it would make sense to generate that list at the for each loop statement thus not having the list in memory twice for example.

```
for each x in myList.where(function(x) x.name = Y)
'do something
next
```

If the LINQ query is unreadable on the for each loop, do I forgo readability and just put it on the for each loop declaration line?

Should I declare the list in its own variable and just bite the bullet and have the list exist twice in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> that list will be in memory twice for the code below

No, it won't.  In your case, the spec is talking about the variable "x" here - not the entire collection.  Remember, and enumerator (any `IEnumerable<T>` or similar) doesn't necessarily even have items in memory.  When created via an iterator in C#, for example, you can have "collections" that are generated as you enumerate over them.  There isn't a "list" of objects (necessarily) that could be copied, even if the language wanted to do so.

> Is the linq query is unreadable on the for each loop

In many cases, I prefer filtering this way.  You can just as easily move this outside of the loop, if you want to make it more clear, as well:

```
Dim filteredCollection = myList.Where(Function(x) x.name = Y)
For Each x in filteredCollection
```

There is no disadvantage to doing this if you find it more readable.

Comment: Cool, Thanks for clarifying for vb and C#

Comment: @gh9: No problem.  The same thing is true in VB, btw - I just mentioned C# since it's easier to write iterators there ;)